# Mono for Android Add pointers to map

Tags: c#, google-maps, monodevelop, google-maps-markers

I am using Mono For Android MapsAndLocationDemo and have a question.

Can I please have some help to place some 'markers' on the current map at certain longitude and latitude points? Also, be able to execute some code when each of these 'markers' are clicked on?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a map overlay. [Here](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API#Adding_Overlays_to_a_Map) is a tutorial

You can implement `ItemizedOverlay`

```
class MonkeyItemizedOverlay: ItemizedOverlay
{
   List<OverlayItem> _items;

   Context context;

   public MonkeyItemizedOverlay (Drawable monkey, Context context) : base(monkey)
   {     
          this.context = context;

          // populate some sample location data for the overlay items
          _items = new List<OverlayItem>{
                  new OverlayItem (new GeoPoint ((int)40.741773E6,
                         (int)-74.004986E6), null, null),
                  new OverlayItem (new GeoPoint ((int)41.051696E6,
                         (int)-73.545667E6), null, null),
                  new OverlayItem (new GeoPoint ((int)41.311197E6,
                         (int)-72.902646E6), null, null)
          };

          BoundCenterBottom(monkey);
          Populate();
   }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
var monkey = Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.monkey);  
var monkeyOverlay = new MonkeyItemizedOverlay (monkey, Context);
map.Overlays.Add (monkeyOverlay);
```

If you wish to add click functionality override OnTap(int)

```
protected override bool OnTap(int index)
{
    var item = _items[index];

    Toast.MakeText(context, index.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could simply add a button directly to the MapView
http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API#MapView_as_a_view_container

Comment: Or Override OnTap(int) method of ItemizedOverlay

Comment: I have the following error: The type or namespace "Drawable" cannot be found.

Comment: Did you add the using directives?? using Android.Graphics; using Android.Graphics.Drawables; If you don't know about using directives follow this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx An easy way to add them is to hover over the class like in this image http://azurecoder.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/md141.png

Comment: Can you please help me with Overriding the OnTap(int) method of ItemizedOverlay?

Comment: I have added the OnTap override to my answer. Add that code to your MonkeyItemizedOverlay class. If you find the answer to be sufficient please mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: Can you please help me to display a simple message when the OnTap method is called, displaying the int of the index?

Comment: I have updated the answer for you again. You need to pass the Context to the constructor and then use it to display a Toast

Comment: Can you please explain what I need to do to "pass the Context to the constructor and then use it to display a Toast" with code if possible. Also, is there a mouse over event for the displayed overlay items?

Comment: The code you need is already in the answer. I have updated the constructor for you

Comment: Is there a mouse over event for the displayed overlay items?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19561/discussion-between-alexw-and-user1690531)